# Run a single application under sock4/5 in windows

Tags: windows, socks

Can i run a single application under sock4/5 in windows, without admin rights? maybe something like socksify but for socks5 in windows

Thankx in advance

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are running in the same account at an equal or higher privilege level as the application, yes it's possible.  But it's not going to be easy to patch the application in memory and intercept all sockets usage.

The easiest approach would probably be to copy the app's exe file and edit the import table so it refers to sproxy.dll instead of ws2_32.dll or winsock2.dll (make the names the same length, it'll make your life easier).  And then write your socks proxy as a DLL stuck in the application directory.

Or were you asking for a tool that already exists, instead of how to program it yourself?  If so, you should ask on SuperUser.com

Comment: how can i do "But it's not going to be easy to patch the application in memory and intercept all sockets usage." ?

Comment: @linuxburst: `WriteProcessMemory` is the Windows function that enables such things.  Are you a programmer or a user?

Comment: ok, your question is going to start racking up close votes.  Don't sweat it, that's how we move things to the sister site, superuser.com.  Or you can flag your question for moderator attention and they can move it for you.